# Matlabpool very slow to open workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have just put together a new rig (i7-4770K, 512gb SSD, 16gb DDR3 2133 mhz ram), and installed MATLAB r2013a. When I invoke the matlabpool command it takes an extremely long time to open up each individual worker (the ones you see open in task manager). On my old rig it was about 10 seconds, but my new one takes 1 minute. I have tried with just 1 additional worker and it takes a long time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the OS? Do you have anything running in the background? What is the CPU load?

Comment: Hi, its windows 8 x64. Its a fresh install so very few background processors are running. The CPU load is basically 0% while I'm waiting for each worker to open.

Comment: Mine takes a while to do it as well, in both Windows and Mac OS X. Not quite a minute, but probably like 25 seconds.

Comment: thanks for the support this definitely seems like a rare yet annoying problem. Its strange it happens on windows and mac. Mine takes about that too, 25 seconds to open each worker, and on a hyper threaded quad that's a long time for 8 workers lol. Maybe its something to do with a certain motherboard / cpu / ram combo...

Comment: I imagine it to be fairly simple, but could you show exactly what you do? Also, did you try it on any other (similar) computers?

Comment: All I do is just type in `matlabpool open local 8`, I have tried with just `matlabpool` or `open local 4`. I actually installed it again on a test hard drive which was a laptop hard disk and it opens matlabpool quickly. But on the ssd which is blazing fast its slow... very strange.

Comment: Same here. R2013a on Windows 8 and 8.1 x64 with a 3770K @ 5GHz. Takes ages to open 8 workers ... each worker takes about 8-10 seconds. I dual-boot in Linux on the same machine, and in Linux it's a snap, less than a couple of seconds per worker. I had no such issues in Win7 x64 with Matlab R2012b or lower as I recall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try executing the following to eliminate one of the newer features (included in versions after MATLAB R2012a) that has caused some people (including myself) problems:

```
distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', false )
```

Mathworks made some changes to the way the local scheduler launches the
workers for R2010a, that change reverts it back to R2009b.

Comment: Amazing, that fixed it! Thanks! I hope this helps a lot of other people searching with this problem.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! The time is reduced by ~ 7 times for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed quite weird. In fact, MathWorks website states:

> For disk-intensive MATLAB applications or to improve the start-up time of MATLAB, you can take advantage of technologies such as solid-state drives or RAID.

You can try to use [this toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775-multicore-parallel-processing-on-multiple-cores), it may solve your problems.