# parfor/for depending on loopsize

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, parfor

Is there a simple way to write a for loop in matlab such that below a certain number (n) of iterations it is a normal for-loop, whereas above this threshold it is a parfor loop?

I want to reduce the overhead that is associated to creating a parallel pool. I tried to set the number of workers to 1 (for less than n-iterations) but still the overhead is non-negligible.

Comment: Why can't you just surround everything with an `if n > 100, parfor ... else, for... end`, or just start the pool in advance?

Comment: I considered these solutions .. but I don't find them satisfying..

Comment: You might want to clarify what you expect from the desired solution, seeing how the "trivial solutions" (and probably the only ones anyway) are not good enough... Have you considered that some other part of your algorithm is possibly much more time-consuming than the creation of the pool?

Comment: 1. The program should be fast(little overhead at least) independently of a parpool being started before.    2. The code should be easy to maintain and expand, hence I don't want duplicate code segment.   I thought of something like a predefined modifier for the parfor (like parpool(1) but this still induces overhead ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Accelerating the startup of `parpool` (might not work on all systems and/or MATLAB versions):

```
distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', false );
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188936/3372061))

#### Option 2:

Set a really long timeout to the `parpool`, so that it surely exists whenever needed:

```
% This will set the idle timeout to 2 hours 
parpool('IdleTimeout', 120);
...
functionThatPossiblyCallsParfor();
```

```
% If pool is already running:
p = parpool;
p.IdleTimeout = 120;
...
functionThatPossiblyCallsParfor();
```

([Source](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116118-change-parallel-preferences-from-code-or-console-in-a-live-session#answer_124358))

#### Option 3:

`if`/`else` based on number of required iterations (this answers the question title):

```
if n > 1E6 % or any other appropriate limit
  parfor (...)
    someFunction(slicedInput1,slicedInput2,...);
  end
else
  for (...)
    someFunction(input1,input2,...);
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah! I didn't think about putting the loop-imside into a function.. thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)